# Extract text information between two define text

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have big text file which has lot of text information but I would like to extract the text between two defined text.
e.g

```
    /begin MEASUREMENT XYZ
        UBYTE
        _CNV_A_R_LINEAR_____71_CM
        1
        100.
        -40.
        160.
        FORMAT "%3.0"
        SYMBOL_LINK "XYZ" 0
/begin IF_DATA EVTRKMNBXERTBK 
    DEFAULT_RASTERS 3 3
/end IF_DATA 
    /end MEASUREMENT
```

i.e /begin MEASUREMENT and /end MEASUREMENT in between this I want to extract text.

My code is:

```
import re
path = r"d:\xyz.txt"
file = open(path, 'r')
lines = file.read()
pattern = re.compile(r'begin MEASUREMENT[\s][\w+](.*?)end MEASUREMENT')
print re.findall(pattern, lines)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(?s)`, this is consider multiple line as a single line. So dot match all characters including newlines.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?s)begin MEASUREMENT[\s](.*?)end MEASUREMENT')
```

So try this,

```
import re
path = "py.txt"
file = open(path, 'r')
lines = file.read()
pattern = re.compile(r'(?s)begin MEASUREMENT[\s](.*?)end MEASUREMENT')
result = re.findall(pattern, lines)
print result[0]
```

**EDITED**

```
t = "XYZ"
pattern = re.compile(r'(?s)begin MEASUREMENT\s+((%s).*?)end MEASUREMENT'%t)
```

Comment: @user2030113 This is works fine for me. What is the result it gives?

Comment: your solution worked for me. i just want to get more specific searching so i want to include "XYZ' in searching. As these names will be different in file.

Comment: I tried this and now it is working. >>>  t = "xyz"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?s)begin MEASUREMENT[\s]%s(.*?)end MEASUREMENT' %t)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
text ="""
    /begin MEASUREMENT XYZ
        UBYTE
        _CNV_A_R_LINEAR_____71_CM
        1
        100.
        -40.
        160.
        FORMAT "%3.0"
        SYMBOL_LINK "XYZ" 0
/begin IF_DATA EVTRKMNBXERTBK 
    DEFAULT_RASTERS 3 3
/end IF_DATA 
    /end MEASUREMENT"""

print text.split("/begin MEASUREMENT")[1].split("/end MEASUREMENT")[0]
```