# Query a pandas dataframe column for a text phrase that may or may not have words within that phrase

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

Goal: To query a pandas dataframe column for a text phrase that may or may not have words within that phrase. At a high level a phrase is "word1 word2". Between word1 and word 2 there may or may not be other words.

This sounds like a dupe, however I tried the SO answers here:

[How to extract a substring from inside a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python)

[Regular expression: matching and grouping a variable number of space separated words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416263/regular-expression-matching-and-grouping-a-variable-number-of-space-separated-w)

[Match text between two strings with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680030/match-text-between-two-strings-with-regular-expression)

[Extract text information between two define text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785211/extract-text-information-between-two-define-text?rq=1)

And a few others and they all miss the case where there are NO words between word1 and word2.

These highly voted solutions all rely on (.+?) between word1 and word2.

Ex: word1(.+?)word2

The above works well if there ARE 1+ words between word1 and word2. However, if there are NO words between word1 and word2 then it doesn't return any results, however I would like it to return results in this particular case as well because the text phrase contains word1 word2.

Also, the data will be cleaned in advance so no need to consider capitalization, commas or other spurious chars.

My code and trials are below. In place of word1 word2 I'm using "pieces delivered" as the text phrase.

Note, they all miss the first example where there are no intervening words between "pieces delivered". It should return "some pieces delivered on time" along with the other rows with "pieces ... delivered".

Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'some pieces delivered on time', 'all pieces not delivered', 'most pieces were never delivered at all', 'the pieces will never ever be delivered', 'some delivered', 'i received broken pieces'])

print("Baseline - Desired results SHOULD contain:\n", df.iloc[3:7])

# The following options all miss one or more rows from the desired results. 
# Just uncomment rgx = to run a regex. 
rgx = r'pieces\s(.*?)\sdelivered'
#rgx = r'pieces\s(\w*)\sdelivered'
#rgx = r'pieces\s(\w*)+\sdelivered'
#rgx = r'pieces\s(\w)*\sdelivered'
#rgx = r'pieces\s(\w+\s)+\sdelivered'
#rgx = r'pieces\s(.*)\sdelivered'
#rgx = r'pieces\s+((%s).*?)\sdelivered'

df2 = df[df.str.contains(rgx)]
print("\nActual results were:\n", df2)
```

Comment: `df.replace('^((?!pieces.*delivered).)*$',float('nan'),regex=True).dropna()` this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `'\s'` is in the wrong position. You need it only if the two words are not adjacent:

```
df[df.str.contains(r'pieces\s(?:.+?\s)?delivered')]
#3              some pieces delivered on time
#4                   all pieces not delivered
#5    most pieces were never delivered at all
#6    the pieces will never ever be delivered
```

Comment: do you even need the `\s` do you even need to capture the `(.*?)`

Comment: @Onyambu There must be at least some separator. Perhaps not a space, but since I don't know better, I'll leave it the way it is.

Comment: well you are right. In that case, you also need separator for the second word. in order for it to be a word. and not to be contained in other words. Makes sense

Comment: wait why capture it? also why use `+`?? what if there is nothing in between? `+`

Comment: anyway have to go, but will leave you with my ++1

Comment: This is not a capturing group, and it is optional (`?`).

Comment: For the purpose of `contains`, any group is non-capturing.

Comment: to me its kind of complicating things since its just simply `pieces\s.*?\sdelivered`

Comment: Your regex requires _two_ spaces between the words.